# Custom Stripe checkout button won't work on mobile

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, stripe-payments

I'm currently integrating Stripe into a website and have come across an issue with custom checkout integration.

I've followed the custom integration instructions on the [Stripe website](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#integration-simple), and it works great on desktop, but unfortunately does nothing on mobile.

I've got a handler in jQuery which fires when my custom button is clicked, and it runs `handler.open({…})`, as per the docs, but the following JavaScript error is logged:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating '(s=this.frame).focus') - checkout.js:2:21656
```

Any ideas?

**Edit:** After lots of playing around I've discovered that it fails to launch in iOS 7 if there's a delay greater than around 1 second to the call.

For example, the following works:

```
setTimeout(function(){stripe_payment();}, 1000);
```

And the following does not:

```
setTimeout(function(){stripe_payment();}, 2000);
```

In the above examples, `stripe_payment()` sets up and calls the handler. As mentioned originally, the same affect can be had when calling the handler after an AJAX call (which presumably takes too long). It's also worth noting that even a 5 second delay on desktop browsers works fine.

Comment: Can you show the code?

Comment: I've added some additional details @AndreiNemes, any ideas?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is caused because `this.frame` is undefined. In Stripe's checkout.js, `this.frame` is actually set just before the error:

```
this.frame = window.open(this.fullPath(), "stripe_checkout_tabview")
```

The problem occurs because `window.open` fails. This is because of the browser's popup blocker; `window.open` can only be successfully called from some event handlers (like a button press). If you're calling it from a (sufficiently long) timeout, it may fail.

You need to call `handler.open({…})` directly from the button's click event. In case you're calling it from the result of an AJAX request, you'll need to refactor your code so that this isn't required.

Comment: FYI, this is also addressed (with examples) in the Stripe docs: https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#integration-more-runloop

Comment: Works! I needed to do this even when using a direct click function, but having a callback in there.

Comment: So where exactly to you call the handler.open?  Would I just add it to the button onclick="handler.open({…})"?