# trying to debug stripe checkout API error for select users on mobile devices

Tags: php, stripe-payments

we have a custom web application that uses stripe's checkout api to process payments. We attempted to move to the new payment intents API but the project stalled due to a problem accomodating our server side payment total calculations.

Anyway, we have a bug that seems to be impacting 2% of users, and they appear to be all using Apple mobile devices. its possibly related to a delay of > 1 sec on mobile as described here [Custom Stripe checkout button won't work on mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24076979/custom-stripe-checkout-button-wont-work-on-mobile)

The symptom is that the checkout API pops over, they enter card details, receive the green "success" check mark, but the code fails at some point and the card is not charged, and the transaction ID is not returned to the browswer so the remainder of the code fails to execute (recording their order in our database, sending an email confirmation, etc).

our webappliation is coded in PHP. I'm wondering if anyone has seen an issue like this, and if so, what were the steps taken to issolate the error and fix it? I wish I could just contract with user quichan for a day and I bet we could debug this and implement the payment intents initiative LOL.
thanks!

here is the code section where we process payments- should I print error messaging on page and work with a customer who's unable to process their order so they can read the print out to me?

```
                    /** charge stripe credit card */
                    $response = $stripeHelper->doOnetimePayment($newOrderStripeToken, $newOrderDeposit, $newOrderDescription, 'usd', $newOrderAccountEmail, $pickupId);
                    $newOrderTransactionId = $response->id;
                    $newOrderPaymentCharged = 1;
                } catch(Stripe_CardError $e) {
                    /** Most likely a card decline error */
                    $stripeError = true;
                    $stripeErrorMessage = $e->getMessage();
                } catch (Stripe_InvalidRequestError $e) {
                    /** Invalid parameters were supplied to Stripe's API */
                    $stripeError = true;
                    $stripeErrorMessage = $e->getMessage();
                } catch (Stripe_AuthenticationError $e) {
                    /** Authentication with Stripe's API failed */
                    $stripeError = true;
                    $stripeErrorMessage = $e->getMessage();
                } catch (Stripe_ApiConnectionError $e) {
                    /** Network communication with Stripe failed */
                    $stripeError = true;
                    $stripeErrorMessage = $e->getMessage();
                } catch (Stripe_Error $e) {
                    /** Display a very generic error to the user */
                    $stripeError = true;
                    $stripeErrorMessage = $e->getMessage();
                } catch (Exception $e) {
                    /** Something else happened, completely unrelated to Stripe */
                    $stripeError = true;
                    $stripeErrorMessage = $e->getMessage();
```

Comment: It needs a lot more details to debug, ie. your frontend code, your live site's URL, steps to reproduces. You can always write to Stripe Support and they would be able to help.

Comment: @orakaro thank you- I just wondered if anyone has had a similar issue on apple moble devices with Stripe Checkout. I'll also message stripe. I have a good front-end developer- he's just not that familiar stripe implementations. I'd be happy to hire a stripe specialist to help him but i've had trouble finding a good one via all the usual contractor sites. Our url is www.redsalmon.com if you are up for some consultation please reach out!